# How do I switch the head to the same model? (Not for shape keys)

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, rigging, armature

Is it possible to get a head swap on the same body as a rig or something? Like switching between characters. Not for shape keys, I mean switch different faces or expressions or turn into a monster.

[image][image]

Comment: Are you asking for a morph transition?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is (if you didn't do any weight painting on your mesh until now):

Select your object, Tab -> Edit mode, then delete all your head vertices.

Tab -> object mode. Move your "new" head to its position in object mode.

Select your new head, Shift-select your body, CTRL-J to join.

Then Shift-select your armature, press CTRL-P -> with automatic weights -> done.